# Uncaught TypeError: Object has no method autocomplete and its blocking to populate dialogue box to delete

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm sorry similar post is already there in the community, But i'm finding it strange. Its working fine but it affected my other views and not allowing other view pages to populate any dialogue boxes..

I tried to fix it by wrapping it in function() like this

```
$('#_auto').autocomplete(function(){
```

But, with this i'm not getting jason values in the _auto textfield and getting unexpected token error with following line.
can anyone help me to solve this please.

```
source: function(request,response){
```

this is my code:

```
$(function () {
    $('#_auto').autocomplete({
        selectFist: true,
        minLength: 2,
        source: function (request, response) {
            var sval = $('#_auto').val();
            //alert(sval);
            $.ajax({
                url: BASE_URL + '/controller/search/',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    'term': sval,
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    var dta = [];
                    orgdetails = [];
                    //response(data.d);
                    for (var i in data) {
                        dta.push(data[i].name);
                        orgdetails[data[i].name] = data[i].id;
                    }
                    response(dta); //response(dta);
                },
                error: function (result) {}
            }); //ajax
        }
    }).focus(function () {
        $(this).trigger('keydown.autocomplete');
    });
});
```

Many Thanks

Comment: I think your missing a `});` at the end

Comment: @DickieBoy - see the scrollbar on the right?  ;)

Comment: on the same page(form page) where i'm getting json values its working perfect.. but its throwing the error for other view pages

Comment: @Archer i do see the scrollbar on the right.

Comment: sorry..thats not the problem..i have pasted part of the code..now you can see });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the for loop should be

```
var dta = $.map(data, function(v, i){
    orgdetails[v.name] = v.id;
    return {
        label: v.name,
        id: v.name
    };
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/MQurb/2/).

Another observation, You can get the current searched term using `request.term` rather than `$('#_auto').val()`

Complete code:

```
$('#_auto').autocomplete({
    selectFist: true,
    minLength: 2,
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: BASE_URL + '/controller/search/',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                'term': request.term,
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                orgdetails = {};

                var dta = $.map(data, function(v, i){
                    orgdetails[v.name] = v.id;
                    return {
                        label: v.name,
                        id: v.name
                    };
                });
                response(dta); //response(dta);
            },
            error: function (result) {}
        }); //ajax
    }
}).focus(function () {
    $(this).trigger('keydown.autocomplete');
});
```

Comment: its not populating values if i'm using so.. :(

Comment: data is json objects with value and id

Comment: it is an array right? like [{"id": "1", "value": "x"}, {...}, ...]

Comment: [Object,Object,Object,Object,Object,Object,Object,Object,]                 0:Object i:"3" name: "xyz" 1:Object id:"5" name: "pqr" etc.....in console.log(data)

Comment: thanks for your reply..its coming from backend like [{"name":"xyz","id":"3"},{""name":"pqr","id":"5"},..........]

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23317/discussion-between-developer-and-arun-p-johny)